# Getting currently clicked co-ordinates relative to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have a function to get the co-ordinates of the recently clicked position with respect to a **div** element without using JQuery which is working fine .

**without jquery (working) :**

```
var Board = document.getElementById("board"); // div element

function mouseListener(e)
{
    var posX = e.clientX - Board.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        posY = e.clientY - Board.getBoundingClientRect().top
    console.log(posX+" : "+posY);
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseListener,false);
```

But this one uses JQuery and giving different co-ordinates as compared to the previous code

**using jquery(not working) :**

```
var Board = $("#board");

function mouseListener(e)
{
   var posX = e.clientX - Number(Board.css("left").replace("px", "")),
       posY = e.clientY - Number(Board.css("top").replace("px", ""));
   console.log(posX+" : "+posY);
}

$(window).mousedown(mouseListener);
```

How to write this properly on jQuery so that it'll work like the first code?

Comment: Board[0]['offsetLeft'] same goes for top, also i prefer .bind(); Like $(window).bind('mousedown',mouseListener);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you have to use `.offset()` to get the same values as with `.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
function mouseListener(e) {
   var posX = e.clientX - parseFloat(Board.offset().left),
       posY = e.clientY - parseFloat(Board.offset().top);
   console.log(posX+" : "+posY);
}
```

[jQuery.fn.offset() Reference here](http://api.jquery.com/offset/);

There are three ways to attach the event-handler. Used in jQuery < 1.7 but still working in newer versions:

```
$(window).bind('mousedown', mouseListener);
```

As of jQuery 1.7 method `.on()` is used, it has the greatest flexibility also for event delegation:

```
$(window).on('mousedown', mouseListener);
```

The third is what you have used, it's only a shortcut and calls internally `.on()`.

[Reference jQuery.fn.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) - - - - [Reference jQuery.fn.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done is absolutely correct logicwise, just minor syntactical mistakes.

```
var Board = $("#board");

function mouseListener(e)
{
    var posX = e.clientX - Number(Board.css("left").replace("px", "")),     //you forgot to put closing braces here and in the next line.
    posY = e.clientY - Number(Board.css("top").replace("px", ""));
    console.log(posX+" : "+posY);
}

$(window).mousedown(mouseListener);
```

Make sure you have used style left and top in the element with id "#board" else output will be NaN : NaN.